# laravel 5.6 new folder in public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create new folder in public whose I named it "manager". Path to this folder is /public/manager. Next to I copy all files from public to this folder, because i think i need the .htaccess file and index.php in that. In the routes I add 2 routes /manager and /manager/list

When I call to /manager all works fine but when call to /manager/list I get error like: 
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

For the test I create new folder in it /public/manager/list and this time I get error like: The requested resource /manager/projects was not found on this server.

I think when I copy all files from /public to folder /public/manager/list everything will work but it not good idea because when I create new routes link I need to add folder... Do you have idea how I can do this? Maybe I need to change htacces or index.php but I dont know how...

Comment: It sounds like you are not very familiar with Laravel. It is an MVC framework. You shouldn't be manually creating views in the public folder. Instead, you put them in the /resources/assets/views folder. I would recommend the tutorials at Laracasts, like this one: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/2

Comment: Yes, I know, but in public I only put my js and css files, but my folder where I have js/css files has the same name as route  for example I have js /public/manager/js/script.js and I have route 127.0.0.1:8000/manager/list. This route not work becase ListController not load, manager folder is lock this action.

Comment: Then you have a route conflict and you should either rename the static asset (css/js) folders or rename the view route path. By the way, you should NOT copy the index.php and .htaccess files into subfolders of your public folder. They are not needed there, and I'm guessing it's causing some of these issues for you. Finally, you may want to call static assets with the asset() helper.

Comment: okey, thanks ;) It is possible to lock a js/css files for only logged users?